# cannot reindex from duplicate axis

Tags: python, data-analysis

When running the following code on my DataFrame

```
df[myNms].isnull().sum() / df.shape[0]
df[myNms].columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
```

It throws `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: It would help if you had an example of your DataFrame, or at least how to construct one so we can replicate your error.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?  For example, df.head(10).to_dict() will produce output that others can then use to test your results.  Also, why is `myNms` and `groups`.